# Is the formula $(\text{ker }A)^\perp=\text{im }A^T$ necessarily true?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix, is the formula $(\text{ker }A)^\perp=\text{im }A^T$ necessarily true?

I'm thinking that rank-nullity would be the simplest and easiest way to prove this, but would applying the definition of linear independence to the components of $(A^T)$ be more illustrative? I'm a bit hung up on this "necessity" issue, and not sure if it has a particular logical meaning in linear algebra.

Comment: Rank-nullity might enable you to prove that the two spaces you mention have the same dimension, but without extra information, this cannot possibly prove that they are the same space.

Comment: "Necessarily" here just emphasizes that the question is whether the identity holds for *all* matrices $A$.

Comment: by definition, any vector in $\ker A$ is orthogonal to every row of $A.$ that means $\ker A \subset (im A^T)^\perp$ or equivalently $im A^T \subset (\ker A)^\perp$

Comment: @abel but is this sufficient to show $(\text{ker }A)^\perp=\text{im }A^T$? Would a contradiction showing a vector $\vec{v}\in \text{im }(A^T), \notin(\text{ker }A)^\perp$ even be possible? My intuition says yes but the definitions seem to leave no exception.

Comment: i believe you need the rank nullity theorem for that. i am not sure you can prove that without it.

Comment: And also [this more recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747559/image-of-adjoint-equals-orthogonal-complement-of-kernel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that the underlying field is $\mathbb R$. As the result does not hold in infinite-dimensional spaces (see closed range theorem), understandably the proof uses a dimensionality argument.

Let $y \in im A^T$ and $x\in \ker A$. Then there is $u$ such that $y = A^Tu$.
This gives
$$
x^T y = x^T(A^Tu) = (Ax)^Tu=0.
$$
Hence $im A^T \subset (\ker A)^\perp$.

Let now $x\in (im A^T)^\perp$. Then $x^T (A^T u)=0$ for all $u$, which implies $(Ax)^Tu=0$ for all $u$. Setting $u:=Ax$ yields $x\in \ker A$, this proves $(im A^T)^\perp \subset \ker A$, and $\ker A^\perp \subset (im A^T)^{\perp\perp}$.

Finally, using $U^{\perp\perp}=U$, which holds for all subspaces of finite-dimensional inner product spaces, we conclude 
$$
im A^T \subset (\ker A)^\perp \subset (im A^T)^{\perp\perp}=im A^T,
$$
which is the claim. The proof $U^{\perp\perp}=U$ uses a dimension argument for subspaces (no rank-nullity). It is easy to see that $U\subset U^{\perp\perp}$ and $\dim U = \dim U^{\perp\perp}$.