# Isomorphism $\ker(B)/Im(A)\cong \ker(A^t)/Im(B^t)$ for chain of linear maps.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, morse-theory

Consider chain of linear maps between finitely dimensional vector spaces $E$, $F$ and $G$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2$:

$E\xrightarrow{A}F\xrightarrow{B}G$

then we take transpose $A^t$ and $B^t$ and consider chain

$E\xleftarrow{A^t}F\xleftarrow{B^t}G$.

Is there any way to prove that $\ker(B)/Im(A)\cong \ker(A^t)/Im(B^t)$?

Note: This question is regarding isomorphism of homologies in proof of Poincare duality for Morse Homology, however I need purely algebraic result here. In the proof maps $A$ and $B$ are given by chain maps for Morse function $f$ while $A^t$ and $B^t$ correspond to chain maps between morse complexes of function $-f$.

Comment: Have you tried arguing these are vector spaces over the same field, of the same dimension and therefor isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see why dimension would be the same. There would have to be some relation between $\ker(A^t)$ and $Im(A)$ which implies that?

Comment: @OSBM Row rank is the column rank and vice versa.

Comment: Using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205388/is-the-formula-textker-a-perp-textim-at-necessarily-true) I have that dimension of $Im(A^t)$ is equal to co-dimension of $\ker(A)$, and other way around by rank nullity. Hence, working in $\mathbb{Z}/2$, I have that $\dim \ker(A^t)/Im(B^t) = n- \dim Im(A) - (n-\dim ker(B) )= \dim ker(B) -\dim Im(A) = \dim \ker(B)/Im(A)$ Then result follows by @jMdA argument.

Comment: Doesn't. Poincare want a natural isomorphism? So just comparing dimensions might not suffice. I would dave tried to uno left exactness of $hom(k,_)$

Comment: @Enkidu but for morse homology I have natural identification between chain complexes for $f$ and $-f$ and boundary maps between chains complexes of $-f$ are given precisely by transpose of maps for $f$. Now, using the fact that $Im(A)=\ker(A^t)^{\bot}$ we get that $\ker(B)/Im(A) =  \ker(B)/(\ker(A^t))^{\bot} = \ker(B) \cap ker(A^t)$ and $\ker(A^t)/Im(B^t)=\ker(A^t)/(\ker(B))^{\bot} =\ker(A^t)\cap\ker(B) $.